# Why is stylesheet ignored if I call the "remote-page"?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm playing around with node.js, right now. I like it a lot.
I have a weird error. If I start the test server with

```
node app.js
```

and navigate to http://localhost:3000, everything is fine. The stylesheet is loaded and everythings looks as it should. But if I navigate to the site via nginx, the site and the stylesheet is loaded, but it seems to be ignored. It's the same source-code. It parsed the same way. And I already tested, that the stylesheet is loaded properly. I really don't have an idea anymore. Anyone else?

Here is my nginx vhost-config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name expressapp.lc;

    root /home/matthias/Documents/webapps/expressapp/public;

    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
        expires         15d;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy   true;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\."
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml   application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried disabling GZIP encoding?

Answer (score 0):

To make things clear, you should:

1. remove the location section that allowing client cache.
2. turn off the gzip compression, e.g. comment out all the gzip staff
3. change the "proxy_set_header Host $http_host" to "proxy_set_header Host $host"